# Exchange 2007 internet email

Tags: exchange-2007

I set-up a exchange 2007 email environment with a Blackberry Enterprise server but its all internal email only. What's the next steps required to enable internet email? I'm going to get my book out but thought I'd ask here first, been a while since I touched any of this since I set it up over a year ago. All email is using name@company.local so I'm guessing I'll need to assign a domain to it also.

Thanks in advanced!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an SMTP send connector to route emails via MX records. If you want inbound email you will need to make Exchange authorative for your domain, and allow anonymous inbound SMTP.